# How can I make a double jump using C# and XNA?

Tags: c#, xna

This is my current code for a single jump, input from the user sets jump to true and a single jump works with no errors, however I cannot produce a second midair jump for my game. I had to do this without unity for school so it is only working with rectangles.

```
if (jumping) //only run when jump has been initiated by space or A
{
    rect.Y = centreY - (int)(Math.Sin(angle) * range); //move player up to a maximum of range's value

    angle += speedY; //gradually reduce player's y by reducing angle's value

    newCentreY = rect.Y;

    if (angle > Math.PI) //reset player to not jumping when angle is greater than 3.14
    {
        angle = 0;
        jumping = false;
    }
}
```

Here's the input handler for jumps:

```
if (userControl.Buttons.A == ButtonState.Pressed || keystate.IsKeyDown(Keys.Space)) //jump when A or space is pressed 
{ 
    jumping = true; 
} 
Jump(userControl, keystate); //jump method
```

Comment: This is an interesting way of doing jumps based off a circle, I like it. Not sure how feasible double-jumps would be with this method though. Mind posting the input handling code for jumps?

Comment: I use this:             
if (userControl.Buttons.A == ButtonState.Pressed || keystate.IsKeyDown(Keys.Space)) //jump when A or space is pressed
            {
                jumping = true;
            }

            Jump(userControl, keystate); //jump method

Answer (score 0):

I think you should make your `angle` to be `0` to continue jumping.

```
if (doubleJumping)
{
    angle = 0;
    doubleJumping = false;
}
if (jumping) //only run when jump has been initiated by space or A
{
    rect.Y = centreY - (int)(Math.Sin(angle) * range); //move player up to a maximum of range's value

    angle += speedY; //gradually reduce player's y by reducing angle's value

    newCentreY = rect.Y;

    if (angle > Math.PI) //reset player to not jumping when angle is greater than 3.14
    {
        angle = 0;
        jumping = false;
    }
 }
```

Comment: Where should be the line that sets `doubleJumping` to true?

Comment: @Steven You should check if the jump button is pressed a second time, and set the variable to `true`.